# Set UIWindow in AppDelegate with SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to init `var window: UIWindow?` to a `UIViewController` programmatically in `AppDelegate`.But I cannot achieve it. When I was updated my Xcode to `Version 11.0 (11A420a)`, in project init section, I choosed to with `Storyboard` not to SwiftUI but I can not achieved to programmatically assign the `UIWindow's` `rootViewController` to a view controller. So first of all, I removed the `Main.storyboard` file, then I hang with `Info.plist` and removed the storyboard section as usual like I do before but there's some configs about `UIApplicationSceneManifest` as shown below. And

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

By the way, for checking out what happens, I tried the init window in `SceneDelegate.swift` and `AppDelegate.swift` file but simulator's screen shows black screen fully. So what I must to do?

Hint: var window: UIWindow! variable description is not added to `AppDelegate` default anymore, its in `SceneDelegate`. So can I set my `rootViewController` from `SceneDelegate` file?

What's the way to achieve fully programmatically this in the new `AppDelegate/SceneDelegate` approach?

Comment: You need to learn and embrace the new scene architecture of iOS 13. Start in the documentation with [Scenes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes?language=objc).

Comment: Then get some popcorn and go to [WWDC 2019 Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019) and watch videos 808, 212, 224, 258, and 259.

Comment: @rmaddy I will watch these, what do you recommend for drinks :) ?

Comment: For anyone looking for an updated "Single View App" Xcode template that supports iOS 12 and 13 as well as supporting either a storyboard or an all-code user interface, see https://github.com/rmaddy/XcodeTemplates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AppDelegate` I removed the lines which contains functions of UISceneSession Lifecyle then it worked it.

```
// MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
```

Than add `var window: UIWindow?` property to `AppDelegate` and inited it and set `rootViewController` programmatically, then worked it but for detail information, I will edit my answer as soon as I learned about `UIScene` workflow.